# Toda classe precisa ter obrigatoriamente um construtor

Tags: php

Sei que é uma duvida de principiante, mas preciso sanar essa dúvida. Pesquisei pela internet e nem sempre os sites entram em "acordo".

Toda classe precisa ter construtor ?

Exemplo:

Posso fazer a classe aluno e não ter construtor e os métodos cadastrar(nome, idade, rm) sendo esse método responsável por fornecer os valores para as propriedades da classe (nome, idade, rm) e o método desativar(id_aluno).

Ao meu ver isso é mais prático no momento de instanciar a classe. Se for apenas desativar o aluno apenas chamada `desativar()`.

Pois se fizer o construtor recebendo as propriedades da classe todo momento que for acessar algum método dela terei que passar todos os valores (nome, idade, rm), mesmo que se para apenas `desativar()`.

Estou pensando errado?  qual a melhor prática?

Comment: Fui tão guela pra responder, que até esqueci de verificar se já tinha a resposta. Tenho que concordar que é a mesma pergunta, praticamente

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Toda classe precisa ter construtor?

Não. Em PHP, classes podem ser declaradas sem a definação de um construtor. Entretanto:

> "Classes que tem um método construtor chamam esse método cada vez que um objeto novo é criado, então é apropriado para qualquer inicialização que o objeto possa vir a precisar antes de ser usado." 
>   [PHP: Construtores e Destrutores](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.decon.php)

Sendo assim, é recomendado que use o construtor para inicializar os atributos que estão vinculados de forma comum a todos os métodos da classe.

Caso o atributo seja específico para um método, inicialize-o no momento da invocação do próprio método.

> (...)
>   Pois se fizer o construtor recebendo as propriedades da classe todo
>   momento que for acessar algum método dela terei que passar todos os
>   valores (nome, idade, rm), mesmo que se para apenas desativar().

Não entendi plenamente sua afirmação. É importante compreender que sempre que uma classe é instanciada com atributos inicializados pelo construtor, essas propriedades estarão disponíveis para qualquer método do objeto até ele ser destruído.

Comment: Na minha " afirmação" eu me refiro quando há vários alunos cadastrados no banco de dados.  Esses são exibidos numa lista.  Então escolho um aluno qualquer p desativar.  Mas se a classe aluno tenha os atributos no construtor todo momrnto terei q passar esses valores,  daí não sei é não vejo lógica de ter q passar esses valores a todo momento

Answer (score 2):

Não, não precisa.

O construtor serve simplesmente para incializar atributos da classe.

A classe `stdClass` por exemplo não possui o método `__construct`.

Em alguns casos, é melhor ter um construtor do que ter que utilizar métodos do tipo `mutator` e `accessor`.

Exemplo com construtor:

```
class Aluno
{
   protected $nome;

   protected $idade;

   public function __construct($nome, $idade)
   {
       $this->nome = $nome; 

       $this->idade = $idade;
   }
}
```

Exemplo sem construtor:

```
class Aluno
{
   protected $nome;
   protected $idade;

   public function setNome($nome)
   {
      $this->nome = $nome;

   }

   public function setIdade($idade)
   {
      $this->idade = $idade;
   }

}
```