# O que é um método " __contruct()"?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Estou iniciando estudos sobre POO, e me deparei com o seguinte método:

```
<?php
class ShopProduct
{
    public $title = "default product";
    public $producerMainName = "main name";
    public $producerFirstName = "first name";
    public $price = 0;
    function __construct($title, $firstName, $mainName, $price)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->producerFirstName = $firstName;
        $this->producerMainName = $mainName;
        $this->price = $price;
    }
    function getProducer()
    {
        return "{$this->producerFirstName}"."{$this->producerMainName}";
    }
}

$product1 = new ShopProduct("1atributo", "2atributo", "3atributo", 7);
print "author: {$product1->getProducer()}"."</br>";

?>
```

Toda classe terá um método construtor ? Por que eu preciso dele ?

Comment: Relacionado: [Para que serve um construtor?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/91)

Comment: Essa vai, mas se pesquisar "método “ __contruct()” não vem nada objetivo...@rray

Comment: @MagicHat não tem problemas. Duplicar perguntas é bom para o site justamente por isso. Criação de múltiplos termos de pesquisa :p

Comment: Não. Toda classe não precisa de um método construtor. A comunidade evita usar métodos mágicos como esse.

Comment: Relacionado: [Toda classe precisa de um construtor?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81131/toda-classe-precisa-ter-obrigatoriamente-um-construtor/81140#81140)

Comment: Em Delphi todas as classes tem um método construtor. Utilizamos eles quando precisamos implementar alguma coisa especifica, como por exemplo alimentar algumas propriedades durante a criação da classe. Outra coisa possível, é sobrepor, sobrecarregar e reintroduzir esse método, quando essa classe herdar de alguma outra classe que já implementa o construtor. O mesmo se aplica para o método destructor.

Comment: @MauroAlexandre não entendi o que você quis dizer...

Comment: @WallaceMaxters em qual parte ?

Comment: Não é obrigatório ter um construtor. Ele, como diz o nome, é o cara que vai construir a classe. Essa construção é invocada quando você instancia sua classe, através do operador `new`. Quando não há nada para se construir na classe, não é necessário utilizá-lo. Vale lembrar também que construtores podem ser herdados. Então você pode ter um construtor na classe pai, porém não na filha.

Comment: A sim, desculpe. Todas as classes que precisam ser criadas vão ter construtores. As classes Helpers por exemplo, não teriam.

Comment: @MauroAlexandre *...A comunidade evita métodos mágicos como esse ...*... "evitar" em que sentido? Quase todas as classes escritas em PHP usam construtor.

Comment: Usar `__contruct()` é a maneira mais correta de definir um construtor (se precisar dele) por dois motivos, 1: em alguma situações bem especificas ter um método com o mesmo nome da classe não garante que ele seja o  consturtor; 2: no php7 definir um método com o mesmo nome da classe gera um [warning](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.deprecated.php) de deprecated, isso veio lá do php4

Comment: Acredito que a questão seja independente de linguagem, por isso vou marcar como duplicata desta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/3635 e desta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81131/3635

Comment: @MauroAlexandre concordo que nem toda classe precisa de um construtor, o construtor deve ser usado quando necessário, agora o que eu não entendi foi *"a comunidade evita"*, o que quer dizer com isto... construtores é uma questão de como você vai fazer as coisas, a questão é necessidade e não evitar. Poderia explicar melhor o seu comentário

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Toda classe terá um método construtor?

Não necessariamente. Um construtor é responsável pela inicialização da classe no ato de instanciação. Ou seja, quando o operador `new` for invocado juntamente com o nome da classe, `__construct` é chamado implicitamente para fazer as operações que você definiu nele.

No seu exemplo, o `__construct` está sendo utilizado para passar argumentos para sua classe e armazená-lo em propriedades.

Um pequeno exemplo para você entender é uma classe onde possui Getters e Setters para definir valores a uma propriedade. Porém, o preenchimentos desses atributos precisam ser obrigatórios, pois são necessários à classe.Nesse caso podemos usar o `__construtor` dessa forma:

```
class Person
{
    protected $name;
    protected $age;

    public function __construct($name, $age)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->age = $age;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of name.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of name.
     *
     * @param mixed $name the name
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of age.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAge()
    {
        return $this->age;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of age.
     *
     * @param mixed $age the age
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setAge($age)
    {
        $this->age = $age;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Observe que `$name` e `$age` são argumentos obrigatórios para o construtor. Então é necessário informá-los no momento da instância da classe, para que a construção ocorra como desejado:

```
$person = new Person('Wallace', 26);
```

O `__construtor` não necessariamente precisa de argumentos para trabalhar como um inicializador, mas fará sentido em usá-lo se você tiver que fazer alguma coisa "automatica" no momento da instanciação da sua classe.

Exemplo:

```
class Document
{
    protected $createdAt;

    public function __construct()
    {  
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime;
    }
}
```

Se você instanciar a sua classe, note que ela vai criar o objeto `DateTime` automáticamente na propriedade `createdAt`.

```
 $document = new Document;

 print_r($document);
```

Resultado:

```
Document Object
(
    [createdAt:protected] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2016-11-16 11:31:42.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => America/Sao_Paulo
        )

)
```

> Por que eu preciso dele?

Como dito anteriormente, para poder definir o que será feito quando a classe foi instanciada.

É claro que você pode não precisar dele em alguns casos, mas isso vai depender muito da arquitetura da classe criada.

Há classes em PHP que não utilizam construtores, como por exemplo `stdClass`.

```
$object = new stdClass;

$object->id = 1;
```

## `__construct` herdado

Vai haver casos que você não vai precisar de declarar o construtor na classe devido a mesma possuir uma herança de outra que já tenha um construtor.

Observe o exemplo abaixo:

```
abstract class Animal
{
    protected $name;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    abstract public function getSound();

}

class Dog extends Animal{

    public function getSound()
    {
        return 'au au';
    }
}

$dog = new Dog('Billy');

$dog->getName(); // 'Billy'
```

Observe que `Dog` herda uma classe abstrata chamada `Animal`. Nesse caso, `Animal` possui um construtor para definir o atributo `name` no ato da instância. Porém não precisei declarar o `__construct` em Dog, devido `Animal` possuir essas funcionalidades desejadas.

## Sobrescrevendo `__construct`

Em PHP, o `__construct` pode ser sobrescrito por uma classe que herda outra.

Veja:

```
class A{

    protected $argument;

    public function __construct() {

         echo "chamei a classe A";
    }
}


class B extends A {  

    protected $argument;

    public function __construct($argument)
    {
       echo "chamei a classe B com argumento $argument";
    }

}

new A(); // "Chamei a classe A"
new B('oi'); // "Chamei a calsse B com argumento oi"
```

Observação importante é que, quando você sobrescreve o construtor, perde completamente o comportamento definido na classe pai (no nosso caso é a classe `A`).

Nesse caso, se precisar definir um construtor para a classe Filha, porém precisar chamar o construtor da classe Pai, você pode usar `parent::__construct` para resolver esse problema.

Veja:

```
class B extends A {  

    protected $argument;

    public function __construct($argument)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        echo "chamei a classe B com argumento $argument";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

Você não precisa dele em todas as classes. Apenas para classes onde você quiser que seja feita alguma ação todas as vezes que ela for instanciada.

Quando você instancia a classe`$minhaClasse = new MinhaClasse()` o método construtor é chamado, se estiver registrado na classe. Você poderia por exemplo gravar um log de que aquela classe foi instanciada (este é um exemplo tosco, mas é assim que funciona).

Você também pode passar dados para dentro da classe através do método construtor. `function __construct($nome, $idade)` e quando você tentar instanciar a classe você terá que passar as variáveis para dentro dela: `$minhaClasse = new MinhaClasse("Rafael", 25)`.

Há também o método `__destruct`, que é chamado sempre que a classe é "desinstanciada", através de um `unset($minhaClasse)` por exemplo. Embora eu nunca tenha usado ou visto uma aplicação disto no mundo real.

Veja a documentação oficial do PHP sobre construtores: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.decon.php

Answer (score 3):

Nem toda classe necessita de um método construtor.
O construtor é basicamente para você iniciar uma classe, eventualmente, é possível setar parâmetros de entrada para esta inicialização, assim como chamar métodos internos. Ele nunca retorna valores:

```
class Carro
{
     private $direcao; //atributo da classe

     public function __construct($param) //parâmetro de entrada
     {
         $this->direcao = $param; //seta o parâmetro de entrada
     }

     public function getDirecao() //retorna o que foi setado no construtor
     {
         return "Direção ".$this->direcao;
     }

}

$carro = new Carro('automática');
echo $carro->getDirecao(); //imprime o retorno do que foi setado
```

Para retornar, é possível também utilizar o método `__invoke()` para invocar o parâmetro direto:

```
class Carro {
   public function __invoke($param) {
      return $param;
   }
}

$carro = new Carro();
echo $carro('Direção automática');
```

Comment: Nem sempre ela serve para poder definir parâmetros. Ela pode ter como funcionalidade tambem simplesmente inicializar atributos internos.

Comment: Você diz chamar métodos de atributos internos?